# which paypal product should I use for the following scenario

Tags: paypal, payment

I want to do the following

1- Accept payment using Paypal account & credit card 
2- The payment will be Authorized and capture later or voided 
3- Payout for users to bank account or Paypal account

Which API  should I use ?
and its okay if I combine more than one API ?

Comment: This is not a question that belongs on StackOverflow. This website is a community of programmers and software developers.

Comment: Im asking which api should I used which I think its blong! im developer and looking for solution to start coding :)

Comment: You should have made that more clear in your question. Notice that you mention "product of PayPal" — their products generally refer to their consumer services, not dev APIs.

Comment: yes you right , well im really confused , the whole thing is not organized in paypal or x.com website

Comment: Well, I found a few things that might help you:  

[The PayPal API reference](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_dcc_hub-outside),  

[The direct payment API intdocuction](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_dcc_hub-outside),  

[And even a dev sandbox!](https://developer.paypal.com)